# Simple XSLT Question: setting inner HTML node attribute values such as <div id="something">

Tags: html, xml, xslt, transformation

Given the contrived XML schema, sample XML input, and sample XSLT below used to transform XML to HTML.  How do I set attributes within tags?  For example `<div id=HouseNumber>`,`<input type="checkbox" id=Zipcode>`, etc?

**Note:** The lack of quotes around HouseNumber and Zipcode are on purpose.  I am trying to put the value of these attributes from the XML input into id="", for="", name="", etc.

**Sample XML Schema**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Location">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="State" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="County" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="City" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="Zipcode" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="HouseNumber" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**Sample XML Input:**

```
<Location>
    <State>California</State>
    <County>Los Angeles County</County>
    <City>Los Angeles</City>
    <Zipcode>90210</Zipcode>
    <HouseNumber>123</HouseNumber>
</Location>
```

**Sample XSLT:**

```
   <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Location">
        <!--Inner HTML example, div has no id-->
        <div class="houseStyle">
            <ul>
                <li><xsl:value-of select="Location/State"/></li>
                <li><xsl:value-of select="Location/County"/></li>
                <li><xsl:value-of select="Location/City"/></li>
                <li><xsl:value-of select="Location/Zipcode"/></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--Inner HTML example again, but how do I
            set the div id to HouseNumber?-->
        <div class="houseStyle" id=HouseNumber>
            <ul>
                <li><xsl:value-of select="Location/State"/></li>
                <li><xsl:value-of select="Location/County"/></li>
                <li><xsl:value-of select="Location/City"/></li>
                <li><xsl:value-of select="Location/Zipcode"/></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Desired HTML Output, where the div tag has an id of a house number:**

```
<div class="houseStyle" id="123">
    <ul>
        <li>California</li>
        <li>Los Angeles County</li>
        <li>Los Angeles</li>
        <li>90210</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could post some sample XML input and what you expect the output to look like.

Comment: Good call Jim, I have to post a sanitized example, but I'll try to make it less obtuse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear what you want here. Do you mean that you want to set your attribute to the result of some XPath expression (like `Delta`)? If so, this should do the trick:

```
<div class="stylishClass" id="{Delta}">
```

Alternatively you may use `<xsl:element>` and `<xsl:attribute>`, as other answers describe, though the typical use case for that is when element/attribute name itself has to be generated.

Comment: Thank you very much this worked very nicely.  Thank you also for the alternative approaches and reasoning behind them.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
<xsl:element name="div">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">stylishClass</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="Delta"/></xsl:attribute>  
 </xsl:element>
```

Example for an anchor tag:

```
<xsl:element name="a">
      <xsl:attribute name="href">http://example.com</xsl:attribute>            
      <xsl:text>My Link Text</xsl:text>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: Thank you this also worked, your answer got it at the same time as Rubens Farias's, but you both helped me out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about code below?

```
    <xsl:element name="div">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">stylishClass</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="Delta"/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you this also worked, your answer got it at the same time as mjmarsh's.  But you both helped me out, thanks!